# Django ManyToManyField does not get cleared

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using a ManyToManyField and want to be able to clear it.

This is my current code (Yes, I do override the save method of the same Object Class)

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.maxparticipants == 0:
        self.participants.clear()
    super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What it does:
It checks if the maxparticipant count is 0 (so there is no participant allowed) and if it's true it should remove every participant from the m2m. When printing `self.participants.all()` I get `Queryset([])` - it works fine.... in theory because it won't get written to the database :/

If you need more details just add a comment :)

Comment: What do you see in database ? clear method just clear the through table of the many to many relations

Comment: `clear()` just breaks the relationship between objects. If you want to remove objects then use `delete()`. For example: `self.participants.all().delete()`

Comment: I just want the relation to be cut of.
-> A participant Object is an user and an user should exit without participating anywhere

Comment: Then `clear` should work fine.  Can you show entire method where you peform a delete?

Comment: Everything I do is changing the maxparticipant count to 0 and then saving the Object. Then the save Method should get called and every single participant should be removed.

Comment: Ok. can you check one thing? remove if statement and just run `self.participants.clear()` every time. Tell if that cleared participants

Comment: Still the same :/ It won't get removed